# msctf/d3d11 crash on exit()

Tags: windows, directx-11

I have an application using DX11.
The debug build works well. But the release build crash on `exit()`.

The stack:

```
000007fef697d630()  
user32.dll!DispatchHookA()  + 0x72 bytes    
user32.dll!CallHookWithSEH()  + 0x27 bytes  
user32.dll!__fnHkINLPMSG()  + 0x59 bytes    
ntdll.dll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue()    
user32.dll!NtUserPeekMessage()  + 0xa bytes 
user32.dll!PeekMessageW()  + 0x89 bytes 
msctf.dll!RemovePrivateMessage()  + 0x52 bytes  
msctf.dll!SYSTHREAD::DestroyMarshalWindow()  - 0x1b7a bytes 
msctf.dll!TF_UninitThreadSystem()  + 0xc4 bytes 
msctf.dll!CicFlsCallback()  + 0x40 bytes    
ntdll.dll!RtlProcessFlsData()  + 0x84 bytes 
ntdll.dll!LdrShutdownProcess()  + 0xa9 bytes    
ntdll.dll!RtlExitUserProcess()  + 0x90 bytes    
msvcr100.dll!doexit(int code=0, int quick=0, int retcaller=0)  Line 621 + 0x11 bytes
```

If I call `LoadLibrary("d3d11.dll")` before calling `exit()`, there is no crash.

Comment: Reply to myself. The crash was caused by dxgi.dll.  Application was quitting and dxgi.dll was unloaded for some reason. But due to reference counting issues, the window was still accessing dxgi objects after dxgi.dll was unloaded. It was a huge application so as a temporary workaround, I have to add LoadLibrary("dxgi.dll") to prevent it from being unloaded.